# mysql data sync change timezone

Tags: mysql, timezone, synchronization

I have two data environments 1) a data source 2) a production database powering a website. These two data environments are in two different timezones.
I am updating my production database incrementally by using

- 1. mysqldump  - for syncing newly added records
- 2. sqlyog sja - for syncing updated records.

I have a column named modified_time (`modified_time` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) in each table to store the last modified time. 
While syncing this data between two timezones I am not able to change the timezone.
I wanted to know how can I change  the source timezone to target timezone while syncing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the db level and even if it were to be possible it would be inefficient, I would say deal with it in your application, its simple, all data is in a different timezone, so you just need to change it by a constant to get your time.

Again if the source data is using UTC (which is recommended) then you dont have any issue at all.

Comment: Agreed on all points except for the part about it being a constant.  That is a common misconception.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: Thanks, I was saying its that simple, but I agree with you 100%